# Missing $ inserted in python code

Tags: floats, captions, texlive, python

I use python3 (with code not from me) to insert data from a database (bsddb3) from the program [GRAMPS](https://gramps-project.org/) into a LaTeX document (TeX Live 2014) and I receive the following error messages:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.1131 ...{Foto_Kurt_Neumann"=1 Kurt Neumann 1915}
                                                  %
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

The relevant part of the python code is:

```py
    self.media_added.add(media_ref.ref)

    path = media_path_full(self.database, media.get_path())
    desc = media.get_description()

    text = ""
    notelist = media.get_note_list()
    for notehandle in notelist:
        note = self.database.get_note_from_handle(notehandle)
        text += le(note.get())

    if intern:
        text += "{\\small\\textit{Bild-ID: %s}}" % (media.get_gramps_id())

    draft_opt = ""
    if draft:
        draft_opt = "draft,"

    tcstar = ''
    if twocolumn:
        tcstar = '*'

    file.write('''%%
    \\begin{figure%s}[tb!p]
    \\raggedright%%
    \\setlength\\fboxrule{.25pt}
    \\setlength\\fboxsep{.25pt}
    \\color{rulecolor}
    \\fbox{%%
    \\setlength{\\imgwidth}{\\linewidth}%%
    \\addtolength{\\imgwidth}{-1pt}%%
    \\includegraphics[%swidth=\\imgwidth,height=1.5\\imgwidth,keepaspectratio]{%s}%%
    }%%
    \\color{textcolor}%%
    \\caption[%s]{%s %s}%%
    \\label{fig:%s}%%
    \\end{figure%s}%%
    ''' % (tcstar, draft_opt, path, le(desc), le(desc), text, media.get_handle(), tcstar))
```

I have hours trying to solve it now, I do not see where the problem is!?

I tried to add the math mode in `\caption`:

```
\\caption[%s]{$%s %s$}%%
```

But run into an even more crypted (related?) issue, I do not know where it comes from.

```
Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before " was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par
```

I am totally lost with this error.

**Edit**

```py
# Latex-Encode
def le(str):
    str = re.sub(r'"\b', r'"', str)
    str = re.sub(r'\b"', r'"', str)
    str = re.sub(r' km\b', r'\\,km', str)
    str = re.sub(r'[\.,!\?]"', r'"', str)
    str = re.sub(r'"', r'"', str)
    str = str.replace("_", "\_")
    str = re.sub(r'(\[[0-9a-e ]+\])', r'\\numberreference{\1}', str)
    str = re.sub(r'(http://[\w\d/\._?&=-]+)',r'\\url{\1}', str)
    str = str.replace('−','--')
    str = str.replace('&','\\&')
    str = str.replace("<u>",'\\rufname{')
    str = str.replace("</u>","}")
    str = str.replace("-)","\"~)")
    str = str.replace("S. ","S.~")
    str = re.sub(r'\)([a-zA-Z])',r')""\1',str)
    str = str.replace("-/","\"~/")
    str = str.replace("-","\"=")
    str = str.replace("/","\\slash{}")
    str = re.sub(r'\\url{([^}]*)"=',r'\\url{\1-',str)
    str = re.sub(r'\\url{([^}]*)\\slash{}',r'\\url{\1/',str)
    str = re.sub(r'\\url{([^}]*)"=',r'\\url{\1-',str)
    str = re.sub(r'\\url{([^}]*)\\slash{}',r'\\url{\1/',str)
    str = re.sub(r'\\url{([^}]*)"=',r'\\url{\1-',str)
    str = re.sub(r'\\url{([^}]*)\\slash{}',r'\\url{\1/',str)
    str = re.sub(r'\\url{([^}]*)"=',r'\\url{\1-',str)
    str = re.sub(r'\\url{([^}]*)\\slash{}',r'\\url{\1/',str)
    str = re.sub(r'\\url{([^}]*)"=',r'\\url{\1-',str)
    str = re.sub(r'\\url{([^}]*)\\slash{}',r'\\url{\1/',str)
    str = re.sub(r'\\url{([^}]*)"=',r'\\url{\1-',str)
    str = re.sub(r'\\url{([^}]*)\\slash{}',r'\\url{\1/',str)
    str = str.replace("#10^00#",'10\\textsuperscript{00}')
    str = str.replace(" #LEBENSLAUF#",'~\\pageref{lebenslauf}')
    return str
    str2 = ''
    for c in str:
        if ord(c)>127:
            str2 += '\mbox{%s}'%c
        else:
            str2 += c
    return str2
```

Comment: Your python code should look out for underscores (and similar characters) and escape them by putting a backslash in front `_` becomes `\_`. Simply typesetting the caption in math mode won't get you satisfying results.

Comment: If I add `str = str.replace("_", "\_")` in the python code, than I get the same runaway argument. I have a bunch of latex ecoding already, see edit.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you now. I gues users with experience in python would also need to see a minimal example that shows the error. It is possible, that your database is faulty, the parser is faulty or ...

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example of the produced LaTeX code? This way we might be able to see what is wrond in your LaTeX code and then in the Python code.

Comment: Yeah! I fixed it!

Comment: Please write an answer to your own question then for others who would have the same problem :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is the following. I had to add a line replacing underscores.

```py
str = re.sub(r'"\b', r'\\glqq{}', str)
str = re.sub(r'\b"', r'\\grqq{}', str)
str = re.sub(r'[\.,!\?]"', r'\\grqq{}', str)
str = re.sub(r'"', r'\\textquotedblleft', str)
str = str.replace("_", "\_")  # replaces the underscores, thank to Johannes for point it out!
```